# Language to Context Free Grammar

Tags: context-free-grammar

I am struggling with converting the following Language into its Context-free grammer

```
    {a^(N) x |x∈{a,b}∗,|x|=N,N≥0}
```

Am a bit lost about how to proceed...I think the below is the pda[image]

Comment: How would you handle `a^nb^b`? What makes this one different?

Comment: whats confusing me is the fact that it can be..say aaa then for x aba...

Answer (score 0):

The language is defined in such a way as to require the following: that all strings have even length; and that the first half of the string consists entirely of a's. This is easily done with a context-free grammar:

```
S -> ASB | e
A -> a
B -> a | b
```

The productions for S guarantee that the numbers of A's and B's is equal and that all A's come before all B's. By making A and B derive only single terminal symbols and by restricting A to only generating a, we ensure that there are only a's in the first half, and that the first and second halves must have the same length.